# Append space to <li> content

Tags: algolia, redactor

I'm using algolia to display search results, and it strips all tags for my product descriptions.

This means that:

```
<ul>
    <li>Feature One</li>
    <li>Feature Two</li>
    <li>Feature Three</li>
</ul>
```

displays as

```
Feature OneFeature TwoFeature Three
```

Unfortunately I'm not able to change how these tags are stripped.

My question: Can I tell Redactor to format an `<li>` with a space at the end, so

```
<ul>
    <li>Feature One </li>
    <li>Feature Two </li>
    <li>Feature Three </li>
</ul>
```

Will be rendered as

```
Feature One Feature Two Feature Three
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are saying Redactor strips out html tags. Will it permit you to add HTML character entities?

For example, could you try to add a non-breaking space (`&nbsp;`) to your data to add your desired space:

```
<ul>
    <li>Feature One&nbsp;</li>
    <li>Feature Two&nbsp;</li>
    <li>Feature Three&nbsp;</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I think he's asking if Redactor can do this automatically to all the LIs, not about manually entering the spaces.